# Best way to handle large Form Collection in Symfony2

Tags: forms, symfony

**Edited my post to be similar to Symfony Cookbook and added some code.**

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html

Note that the Entity/Form code posted in the part is the same as the one in the doc linked above.

I have a "Task" entity, which is linked to a "Tag" entity.To keep it simple, "Task" has a single field "description", and a "tag" has a single field "name".A "Tag" is linked to one "Task", and a "Task" is linked to many "Tags".

**Entity:**

```
class Task
{
    protected $description;
    protected $tags;

    public function __construct()
    { $this->tags = new ArrayCollection(); }

    public function getDescription()
    { return $this->description;}

    public function setDescription($description)
    { $this->description = $description; }

    public function getTags()
    { return $this->tags; }

    public function setTags(ArrayCollection $tags)
    { $this->tags = $tags; }
}

class Tag
{
    public $name;
}
```

At the moment, I use a Collection of "Tags" in the "Task" form to edit all them at once, as described in Symfony CookBook:

**Form:**

```
class TagType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('name');
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Acme\TaskBundle\Entity\Tag',
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'tag';
    }
}


class TaskType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('description');

        $builder->add('tags', 'collection', array('type' => new TagType()));
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Acme\TaskBundle\Entity\Task',
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'task';
    }
}
```

But a problem appears when I create a collection of "Tags" larger than a thousand elements. At this time, the form take seconds and seconds to load, and sometimes it crashes due to memory.

```
$task = new Task();

$tag1 = new Tag();
$tag1->name = 'tag1';
$task->getTags()->add($tag1);
$tag2 = new Tag();
$tag2->name = 'tag2';
$task->getTags()->add($tag2);
//Create a couple thousand more item here ...

//The script crashes here, when the form is being created
$form = $this->createForm(new TaskType(), $task);
```

The error does not come from Doctrine, which handles very well the whole thing, but from Symfony Form.

Is it a good idea to handle my form using Symfony2 built-in form system (with Collections) in this case, or should I handle it like in the old days, with raw html inputs and server-side validation/saves?

Comment: Post your code and what part of the symfony docs you're referring to?

Comment: I edited my post with the link to Symfony Cookbook about Collections. My code has no importance here, I'm just using Form Collections as described in the first part of the link (all "tags" entities are loaded with my "product" entity) when I do "$this->createForm".

Comment: Yes, I skipped the whole Symfony Form and did it by hand

Comment: I know this is old, but could you solve the problem?

I'm dealing with the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I'm wondering if your issue has nothing to do with the form part of this, but the hydration of the tag objects. If you're asking doctrine to hydrate a ton of objects, it's going to use a big chunk of memory. You may want to look into another method of hydrating the tags, perhaps HYDRATE_ARRAY instead of HYDRATE_OBJECT.

Comment: Yes, I think the biggest part of the problem comes the Doctrine hydration. Is it possible to create/bind my form based on an entity hydrated as an Array rather than an object ? Will I still be able to validate the entities / save them without handcoding everything ?

Comment: How many tags are we talking here?  I'm able to load up 500 entities into a multiple expanded entity list pretty quickly using the normal method.

Comment: Edited my post with more informations. The problem does not come from Doctrine, but from Symfony $this->createForm() methods with Collections.